# Crontab - Ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible, cron

I want to backup some switch configuration with ansible and trigger the the script by ansible daily.

If I use the cli manually, no problem in the directory `ansible-playbook test.yml`

With crontab

```
*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/ansible-playbook /home/toto/Ansible/test.yml
```

I have the following message.
The backup directory is in /home/toto/Ansible/

```
TASK [RENAME BACKUP] ***********************************************************
fatal: [192.168.109.10]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "b202fa1d99ce10d27b223290ac40bc70c54639b3", "msg": "Destination directory ./backup does not exist"}
fatal: [192.168.109.11]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "93771b9c4b2455fafc0e9abe2aa83e1edf97867f", "msg": "Destination directory ./backup does not exist"}
fatal: [192.168.109.12]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "d121ab08b4f431f9b738c13f319c7ebd80694f63", "msg": "Destination directory ./backup does not exist"}
```

Someone has an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: The error message is clear: The directory that you are trying to copy the back-up to does not exist. Also, please add any relevant code to your question.

Comment: ./backup on the remote system can probably never be correct...use a absolute path better

Comment: You did not provide your playbook which makes it hard to have a clue on what is going wrong exactly. Moreover, from you path, I suspect you test the playbook running as `toto` whereas you  cron it with user root.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that works, just change the directory fist

```
*/2 * * * * root cd /home/toto/Ansible && ansible-playbook test.yml
```